# Trying to copy a file to the windows autoexec folder in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

im trying to copy a file to 
c:\users\%username%\%AppData%\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

so far i have tried:

```
echo . > test.txt
move test.txt c:\users\%username%\%AppData%\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\StartMenu\Programs\Startup
```

with

> The file, directory or volume's syntax is incorrect.
>   *(Had to translate this bit so it might not say the same exact thing on your pc.)*

as a result.

I am a beginner at this and im self-teaching this language so please forgive me if i make silly mistakes that can be easily corrected without noticing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do some debugging and you'll see why it's going wrong. In a Command Prompt window, type:

```
echo %AppData%
```

You'll see that this environment variable contains everything you need from the drive letter all the way to "Roaming".

So you need:

```
move test.txt "%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
```

The quotes around the second parameter are required because the "Start Menu" directory contains a space in its name.

Comment: Thank you! I will keep your tip in mind and take a look at the debug before asking on here.